# Find two vectors from one

Tags: vectors, circles, triangles

I've made a quick sketch of my problem so it's easier to understand.
My goal here is to find vector a.

I start out with only knowing the length and direction of the vector c, the hypotenuse of the triangle.
I also know that the angle C is 90 degrees the radius of the circle, b, and that a is tangent to the circle.

By using Pythagoras I can find the length of a, but I don't know how to find vector a.

I probably could make a circle around the point at B with a radius of 'a', and the find the intersection between the two circles.

Are there any easier solutions?

[Quick Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FkBUY.png)

Comment: do you have numerical values for the centre of the circle, vector c and the radius b?

Comment: This is something that is to be programmed, so there are no real values

Comment: would it be sufficient for you to know the gradient of the tangent - presumably you could use this information to make the vector a?

Comment: Yes, that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $A$ is the origin, so the equation of the circle is $x^2+y^2=b^2$.

Since the vector $\underline{c}$ is known, assume we have the coordinates of $B(p,q)$

A line with gradient $m$ passing through $B$ is $$y=mx-mp+q$$

Solving this simultaneously with the circle, and applying the condition that the resulting quadratic equation in $x$ must have double roots because of the tangent point leads to, after some algebra, to the following quadratic equation in $m$:
$$m^2(p^2-b^2)-2mpq+q^2-b^2=0$$

From this you can extract the two possible values of $m$, namely $$\frac{pq\pm\sqrt{b^2p^2+b^2q^2-b^4}}{p^2-b^2}$$

Comment: This solution fails when $p = \pm b$.

Comment: Of course. Then $m=\infty$ or $m=\frac{q^2-b^2}{2pq}$

Comment: On the other hand, the angle may still be well-defined. If you use the $Ax + By + C = 0$ form of the line-equation, you can handle these cases as well  without any special-case-ing.

Answer (score 0):

You know the lengths of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ (which I'm going to call $a$ and $b$).

Let $$
t = atan2(b, a)
$$
Then the angle of vector $\vec{a}$ is the angle of $\vec{c}$, minus $t$.

(angles measured counterclockwise from the $x$-axis).

Comment: The angle between vector c and vector b is not known, if that is what you mean by 'angle of c'

Comment: And did you mean 'atan2(b, a)' or '(vector_a) * tan2(b, a)' ?

Comment: You wrote "[I] start out with only knowing the length and direction of the vector c, " I assumed that by the "direction" of vector $c$, you meant its angle relative to some axis (usually the positive $x$-axis). To answer your second question, I meant what I wrote (until someone else mangled it by editing).